# Erratum for Billingsley’s $\textit{Probability and Measure}$, Problem 33.9(c)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, proof-verification

This is yet another verification request on a(n allegedly) false statement in Patrick Billingsley’s *Probability and Measure* textbook. I have been self-studying this excellent book for quite a while and my aim here is to document some minor mistakes for my records and for the public (see also [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1970203/erratum-for-billingsley-s-textitprobability-and-measure-problem-32-13) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411395/error-in-billingsley)).

---

This time, I am concerned with Problem 33.9(c) on page 443 in the third edition of the book. The problem states the following:

> Show that conditional probabilities can be defined as genuine probabilities on spaces of the special form $(\Omega,\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_k),\mathbb P)$.

That is, suppose that the probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr F,\mathbb P)$ is such that the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr F$ is generated by a finite number of random variables $X_i:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. A *conditional probability* of any fixed set $A\in\mathscr F$ with respect to a $\sigma$-subalgebra $\mathscr G\subseteq\mathscr F$ is defined as a function $\mu(A,\omega):\Omega\to\mathbb R$ such that

- the function $\omega\mapsto\mu(A,\omega)$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-subalgebra $\mathscr G$;
- the function $\omega\mapsto\mu(A,\omega)$ is integrable: $$\int|\mu(A,\omega)|\,\mathrm d\mathbb P(\omega)<\infty;\quad\text{and}$$
- for any $G\in\mathscr G$, one has that $$\int_G\mu(A,\omega)\,\mathrm d\mathbb P(\omega)=\mathbb P(A\cap G).$$

It can be proven via the Radon–Nikodym theorem that conditional probabilities—according to the definition above—always exist. The extra statement to be proven in this exercise is that the conditional probabilities can be chosen in such a way that

- $\underline{\text{$\mu(\cdot,\omega)$ is a genuine probability measure on $\mathscr F$ for} \textit{ every } \omega\in\Omega}$,

as long as the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr F$ is generated by a finite number of random variables. (A common terminology is that this condition requires that the conditional probability be *regular*.)

---

While conditional probabilities always exist, it may be possible that the fourth underlined condition above can in no way be satisfied. Indeed, Problem 33.11 on the same page of the textbook outlines a counterexample: conditional probabilities do exist, but they cannot be constructed in such a way that the extra underlined condition above is satisfied.

This counterexample in Problem 33.11 relies on the construction of a somewhat pathological yet very interesting $\sigma$-algebra, which had been discussed in detail earlier in the textbook—see Problem 4.10 on page 66. If you take the claim of Problem 33.9(c) at face value, then you must conclude that the pathological $\sigma$-algebra constructed in Problem 4.10 cannot have been generated by a finite number of random variables. Yet, if you define $X_1(\omega)\equiv\omega$ for every $\omega\in\Omega$ and $X_2$ as the indicator function of the set $H$ (in the context and notation of Problem 4.10), then it is not difficult to show that the pathological $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr F$ in question is, in fact, $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$, the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$.

**Therefore, the statement of Problem 33.9(c) cannot be true.**

---

In fact, I have tried very hard to prove this statement before realizing that it is false. ([This other thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014536/if-any-two-sets-on-a-pi-system-with-certain-properties-have-equal-probability/2014814#2014814) is related to the process of my attempted proof.)

I think the root of the problem is the following subtlety. Theorem 33.3 on page 439 yields a construction of the *conditional distribution* of a random variable (or random vector), which concept is closely related to that of conditional probability. This theorem shows that the conditional distribution can always be defined to be a genuine probability measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb R^k$) for every realization $\omega\in\Omega$ of the sample space.

However, a probability distribution is a pushforward measure: it is defined on the real line via the corresponding random variable, and it “pushes forward” the probabilistic behavior of the random variable on the underlying sample space $\Omega$ onto the real line $\mathbb R$.

What Problem 33.9(c) seems to ask to do is consider a $\sigma$-algebra generated by a finite number of random variables, take the conditional distribution (which is always well-defined pointwise), and “pull back” the random variables’ values’ probabilistic behavior on $\mathbb R^k$ onto the sample space. However, this may not be possible to do in such a way that the resulting conditional probability (defined on the sample space) is a genuine probability measure *pointwise* (that is, such that the underlined extra condition above holds). The reason is that while pushforward measures are easy to construct, the analogous construction of a hypothetical “pullback” measure is problematic and usually ill-defined (unless special addition conditions, such as injectivity and Borel isomorphy, are imposed).

---

Any feedback and comments are appreciated.

Comment: I have also been working through Billingsley, but am still at ~Chapter 17. One possible issue I see with your counterexample, is that usually when Billingsley refers to measurable functions without specifying any $\sigma$-fields, he means Borel-measurable functions. I am guessing in your counter-example $X_1$ is *not* measurable w.r.t. Borel sets and $X_2$ is definitely *not* (since $H$ is not measurable). Maybe this is why it breaks down and it actually works if you assume $X_i$ are Borel-measurable?